# How to generate an error message when a particular cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in excel in one column i have system id,name,salary,date in other column i need to enter the corresponding values. If there is no value for a particular row then an error message should be generated. Is there a way to do it in excel??
example:

```
Column 1   Column 2
system id  10
name       
salary     1000
date
```

In the above example there is no data for name and date columns.Is there any way that we can automatically generate an error message saying that there is no  data in that particular cell. Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can check whether a cell is blank or not with the `isblank()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Data Validation available in Data menu. I think it can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if()` and `isblank()` together as shown in the example below

```
Row  A           B      C
1    system id   10     =if(isblank(B1),"No value","Value present")
2    name       
3    salary     1000
4    date
```

Comment: The solution will not generate the error message @abc desires.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use both conditional formatting and a formula.

1. Setting the Stage:

We will apply conditional formatting to cell B1 and use the format painter to apply the change to all the other cells.

[image]

2. Click "Conditional Formatting" and navigate to "New Rule":

[image]

3. Click "Use formula to determine which cells to format" and enter the formula "ISBLANK(YourCellHere)" into the text box.  Replace "YourCellHere" with the first cell you want to  apply conditional formatting to.  In this example "B1" is that cell. You will also need to specify how blank cells should be formatted.  This is accomplished by selecting options via the "Format..." button.  In this example's  "Red" was selected for the "Fill".

[image]

4. Click the "Format Painter" button and drag the brush over the cells the conditional formatting should be applied to.

[image]

Comment: Hi @abc if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.